# Monochrome BitMap Library

Tags: c++, c, graphics, bitmap

I am trying to create a piece of software that can be used to create VERY large (10000x10000) sized bitmaps. All I need is something that can work in monochrome, since the required output is a matrix containing details of black and white pixels in the bitmap. The closest thing I can think of is a font editor, but the size is a problem.

Is there any library out there that I can use to create the software, or will I have to write the whole thing from the start?

Edited on May 25: OK, so I've been searching around and I have found that using the GtkTree Widget is a good way to create grids. Has anybody tried that with the large sizes that I require? And if so, can it be made to look like a drawing surface rather than a Spreadsheet like view?

Comment: What operations do you need to perform on the "image"?  Do you need to display it?  Do you need to print it?  What platform(s) does it need to run on?

Comment: 10,000 x 10,000 is really not that large.  Medical imaging typically uses that order of resolution.  Have you confirmed that some of the common graphics libraries really don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use bitmap objects, like gdk pixmaps if you use GTK?

10,000 x 10,000 pixels with a depth of 1 (monochrome) is 100,000,000 bits, which is 12,500,000 bytes, around 12 megabytes.

Not that large.

Comment: Agreed the images out of a good desktop scanner are *much* bigger.